# Update extension for multiple files at once on Amazon S3

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I'm having about 1 million files on my S3 bucket and unfortunately these files were uploaded with wrong extension. I need to add a '.gz' extension to every file in that bucket.

I can manage do that by using aws cli:

`aws s3 mv bucket_name/name_1 bucket_name/name_1.gz`

This works fine but the script is running so slow since it moves the file one by one, in my calculation it'll take up to 1 week, which is not acceptable.

I wonder if we have any better and faster way to achieve this goal ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try S3 Browser which supports multi thread calls.
http://s3browser.com/

I suspect other tools can do multi thread as well, but the CLI doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

There's no renaming feature for S3 files/bucket so you need to move or copy/delete files. If the files are big, it can indeed be a bit slow.

However there's nothing that prevents you to wait for a request to complete to continue with "renaming" the next file in your list, just process it.